# ActiveMQ Artemis, the console does not comes up after the slave is restarted as master on failover

Tags: activemq-artemis

ActiveMQ Artemis: the console(of slave) does not comes up after the slave is restarted as master after failover. In logs I can see hawtio services being destroyed. Can anyone tell why hawtio services are being destroyed on slave? Is this the correct behavior? If not, how can I stop it from being destroyed?

Artemis Version: 2.5.0

Logs:

```
Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Backup Server version 2.5.0 [null] started, waiting 
live to fail before it gets active
AMQ221024: Backup server ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=2dd29ee1-2ce9-11e8- 
a95e-0050568c47be is synchronized with live-server.
AMQ221031: backup announced
Keycloak integration is disabled
Initiating quorum vote: LiveFailoverQuorumVote
Waiting 30 seconds for quorum vote results.
AMQ221060: Sending quorum vote request to 
stomvjms11.xz.xyz.com/10.21.46.44:8003: ServerConnectVote 
[nodeId=2dd29ee1-2ce9-11e8-a95e-0050568c47be, vote=false]
AMQ221061: Received quorum vote response from 
AMQ221070: Restarting as backup based on quorum vote results.
[io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter] Destroying hawtio authentication filter
[io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Destroying hawtio services
[org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Destroyed artemis- 
plugin plugin
[org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Destroyed 
activemq-branding plugin
[org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221002: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 
Message Broker version 2.5.0 [2dd29ee1-2ce9-11e8-a95e-0050568c47be] stopped, 
uptime 4 minutes
[org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: backup Message Broker 
is starting with configuration Broker Configuration
```

Comment: Please change styles for others to easy to read

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're seeing is a bug. It was originally reported in [ARTEMIS-1737](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1737). It's fixed in [Artemis 2.5.0](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/download.html).

Comment: Thanks Justin but I am using 2.5.0

Comment: I just tested this scenario with a fresh install of 2.5.0, and I do not see the web console being destroyed during failback. Right after I started the live and the backup I opened a browser window to the console of the slave. At first I don't see any acceptors or addresses deployed (since it isn't active), but when I kill the live the console updates with the acceptors and addresses. Then when I restart the live and trigger failback the console updates again removing the acceptors and addresses. Everything appears to be working as expected. Do you have steps to reproduce this on 2.5.0?

Comment: I am running the setup on 4 boxes, one master - slave in group 1 and another in group 2. On killing the master of any one of the group, slave goes down too. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lt859yMVkv7h5DamC_dSK9i0EFfQS7j2) is the broker configuration of master. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15DTjWmVe-uEc_CXhPVnRqG923O_5CKjk) is the broker configuration of slave. And [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r8-_WQNxgPUEwaeIL_KAUx5z5ygOlDgn) are the full logs.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by, "On killing the master of any one of the group, slave goes down too." Are you saying the entire slave broker goes down (i.e. fail-over does not occur) or that the web console isn't available. Are 4 nodes required to reproduce the problem or is 2 nodes sufficient? You provided a link to the "full logs," but that looks like a partial log of one slave rather than the complete log of all 4 brokers. As previously requested, please provide steps to reproduce. Ideally this would be as simple as possible.

Comment: My bad I was unable to explain properly. So here are my observations and steps to reproduce:

In version 2.4.0, i was able to reproduce this on setup of 2 boxes, one master and one slave. But in version 2.5.0, it seems to be working fine on setup of 2 boxes (could be sprodiac) but i was able to reproduce this issue on a setup of four boxes.
(Box 1 - Master)
(Box 2 - Slave)
(Box 3 - Master) 
(Box 4 - Slave)

Comment: Steps to reproduce :
Step 1: Setup the brokers as per the configuration provided in my previous comment
Step 2: Stop(artemis stop) the master broker (say box 3)
Step 3: As per the [logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Eq3c1K6pcriSVYYdAWVAtOifD-s7A8gH) of slave(box 4) hawtio services are destroyed (line 206 in logs) and the *console of slave(box 3) goes down*.

Comment: As I can see in the [logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Eq3c1K6pcriSVYYdAWVAtOifD-s7A8gH)(line 225), slave (box 4) becomes live but i cannot see it on any port. I don't know if it is still running in the background or not.
While all this happens, Box 1(Master) and Box 2(slave) seems to work fine.
And here are the actual "full logs"
[slave logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Eq3c1K6pcriSVYYdAWVAtOifD-s7A8gH) | 
[master logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Rvbsj-9TJnXWDhVQZ-NeL2r-Y2DuqC4C)

Comment: Instead of putting these details in a bunch of comments you should edit your original question and put them in there. Also, I would encourage you to create a test-case which is automated as possible. It's typically pretty easy to to do this by modifying one of the examples shipped with the broker. There are many clustering and HA examples that start/stop multiple brokers which you could use as a starting point. Testing this kind of stuff manually just takes too much time (which I don't have).